# CakePHP 2.2 Categories Tree Scaffolded - Parent not Showing

Tags: cakephp, tree, scaffolding, cakephp-2.2

I'm using CakePHP to manage a web application that has some categories, which have the following SQL database. I've included my controller and class name. Basically I have no need for anything other than what I would consider the "normal" functionality for categories.

A tree structure has parent_ids being other categories, which are optional (for example, for top-level categories.

The scaffolding is being applied correctly, and if I go to /admin/categories, I can CRUD them to my heart's content, but the "parent" drop-down it creates is blank.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this too complicated for the scaffolding?

```
CREATE TABLE `ck_categories` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `lft` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `rght` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

class CategoriesController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold = 'admin';


        public function index() {
            $data = $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
            debug($data); die;
        }
}

class Category extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Category';
    var $displayField = 'name';

            public $hasMany = 'Product';
            var $actsAs = array('Tree');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add association with parentCategory ID.

```
var $belongsTo = array
(
    'ChildRecored' => array
    (
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This helped, but it doesn't allow me to NOT select a category - like for a parent category. Is this possible using scaffolding?